# How can I truncate latitude and longitude in Presto without rounding or cutting off 0s?

Tags: sql, presto

I have an issue where I am attempting to truncate latitude and longitude to 3 decimal places, but I don't want to `ROUND` because it will change the location.

I tried `CAST((TRUNCATE(lat * 100) / 100) AS VARCHAR)` but if I do that, it will remove trailing zeros (if the latitude is -122.200 it will return -122.2

I thought I could use `RPAD` to select a portion of the string (in this case '.') and then pad it a certain number of spaces (in this case 3 spaces. But when I try `RPAD(CAST(lng AS VARCHAR), 3, '.')` it returns -12

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expression:

```
SELECT
 regexp_replace( CAST(-122.219980 as varchar), '\.(\d{1,3})\d*', '.$1' ),
 regexp_replace( CAST(-122.200911 as varchar), '\.(\d{1,3})\d*', '.$1' )
```

will result in:

```
-122.219    -122.200
```

like requested.